# LinkedIn post comment with mention not working

Tags: linkedin-api

We were using LinkedIn API Version 202306, and we had to use an undocumented way to mention persons using:

```
"attributes": [
      {
        "length": 25,
        "start": 0,
        "value": {
          "com.linkedin.common.MemberAttributedEntity": {
            "member": "urn:li:person:ARUhKQtm5a"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

But, starting with version 202307, this is resulting in status error: 422
{"message":"ERROR :: /message/attributes/0/value/com.linkedin.common.MemberAttributedEntity :: unrecognized field found but not allowed\nERROR :: /message/attributes/0/value :: "com.linkedin.common.MemberAttributedEntity" is not a member type of union","status":422}

We've tried the microsoft documented schema [(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/comments-api?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http#sample-request-body](Sample Request Body)), and we cannot get it work:
{"message":"ERROR :: /object :: field is required but not found and has no default value\n","status":422}

Has someone succeed in using this feature?

I've tried all the versions, but it works only in the 202306 version. Following versions are not working and there is no doc.

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28urn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A7146485071443652608%2C7166522137988599809%29/comments HTTP/1.1
x-li-format: json
LinkedIn-Version: 202306
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Authorization: Bearer ...
Host: api.linkedin.com
Content-Length: 465

{
  "actor": "urn:li:organization:101413098",
  "parentComment": "urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:7146485071443652608,7166522137988599809)",
  "message": {
    "text": "Santiago Acosta Ottonelli cierro por SL",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "length": 25,
        "start": 0,
        "value": {
          "com.linkedin.common.MemberAttributedEntity": {
            "member": "urn:li:person:ARUhKQtm5a"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This request works with api version 202306, but doesn't with 202307